# Error trying to export an Sqlsrv database table to excel works

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, phpexcel

Hey am trying to export an Sqlsrv database table to excel works well when am not export the datetime column but once i do i get this error:
 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpExport\src\PHPExcel\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php on line 86

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ComSec_meeting ORDER BY submission_date";
```

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

```
try {
        // Set value binder 
        PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() ); 
    $sheet = new PHPExcel();

    // Set metadata
    $sheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Mozes')
                           ->setLastModifiedBy('Mozes')
                           ->setTitle('Try')
                           ->setKeywords('Try');

            // Set default settings
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(
            PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);

    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
            PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Lucida Sans Unicode');
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(12);


            // Get reference to active spreadsheet in workbook
    $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();

    // Set print options
    $activeSheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(
            PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            ->setFitToWidth(1)
            ->setFitToHeight(0);

    $activeSheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&B&16' . 
            $sheet->getProperties()->getTitle())
            ->setOddFooter('&CPage &P of &N');

            // Populate with data
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

    $colHeaders = array_keys($row);
    $col = 'A';
    $rownum = 1;    

            // Set column headings
    foreach ($colHeaders as $header) {
        $activeSheet->setCellValue($col . $rownum, $header);
        $activeSheet->getStyle($col . $rownum)->getFont()->setBold(true);

        $col++;
    }

            // Populate individual cells with data
    do {
        $col = 'A';
        $rownum++;
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rownum, $value);

                    }
    } while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt));


             // Format individual columns
    $activeSheet->getStyle('E2:E' . $rownum)->getNumberFormat() ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);
            $activeSheet->getStyle('F2:F' . $rownum)->getNumberFormat() ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);

    // Give spreadsheet a title
    $activeSheet->setTitle('Try');![enter image description here][1]

    // Generate Excel file and download
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="TryOut.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save('php://output');


} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date values from your database resultset (the values that you're setting in columns `E` and `F`) to an MS Excel serialized datetime value using `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` before trying to set that value in a cell

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
    if ($value instanceof DateTime) {
        // Convert DateTime values to MS Excel serialized timestamps
        $value = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($value);
    }
    $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rownum, $value);
}
```